# Mirc, emulate akicklist saving in file the ip

Tags: mirc

someone can suggest me as to do this:

if i type:

/akick nickname

Nickname should to be kicked and banned from current channel and to same time i need to save in a file (for example: akicklist.txt) the IP address of nickname.
In ON JOIN event, i need check if ip address of nickname that joined in channel is present in akicklist.txt and if result is true then proceed with a kick and ban to it.

Thanks very much, for help.

Comment: That's called, there are plenty scripts out there. Have you tried anything?

Comment: me not found something of specific for to do a sequential research in a file and return true/false. i other Language as delphi is easy but here i have some problem.

Answer (score 0):

Those kinda lists are called Black/Enemy/Shit/etc List's..
You can find those in google as "mirc shit list"...

http://www.mircscripts.org/comments.php?cid=3653
http://www.mirc.net/projects.php?go=1089290479&get_review=1